# Multiple circular left shifts and operations

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I don't understand circular shifts.

I did search and found the method below, but the inputted value doesn't give the expected result:

```
public static uint RotateLeft(this uint value, int count)
{
    return (value << count) | (value >> (32 - count));
}
```

Inputting `211` should give `158` when shifted `3` times.

Comment: 211 shifted how many times?

Comment: "Inputting 211" is it `value` or `count`? Where is the second argument?

Comment: Shifted 3 times, sorry.

Comment: How can `211` give `158` when shifting the `uint` left? Are you sure the `uint` is the exact type you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your expected result is byte based while your code is 32 bit based. For bytes, try this:

```
public static byte RotateLeft(byte value, int count)
{
    return (byte)((value << count) | (value >> (8 - count)));
}
```